# Can anyone provide a link to a RestKit 0.20 tutorial that works

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to get Ray Wenderlich's RestKit tutorials (http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial) to work using RestKit 0.20 and I'm having no luck making it work.  Has anyone been able to migrate the tutorial successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://nsscreencast.com/

You can try these ones. You need to pay to watch the actual videos, but there is alot of sample code that goes along with them.

Good Luck!

Comment: The NS Screencast examples are great and they are using the pre release version of RestKit .20.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

[RKGist](https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/) is the official tutorial project under the RestKit repository. The tutorial covers most of the latest APIs in 0.20.0rc1 and was last updated 6 days ago. Keep an eye on that repo for updates.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

It provides the basic of object mapping for response and request for restkit 0.20.

Comment: Welcoem to stack overflow! It is a good practice quote the important part from links.